# How remove text after extension .jpg scraping - php

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I have this url for scrapping: example.com/upload/produse/epilatoare/SE810%20Face.jpg?maxwidth=800&maxheight=800
I want remove all character after .jpg and I don't know how make this.

The code for scraping website is:

```
if(isset($this->request->post['image_scrapper'])){
                $imageQuery = $xpath->query("//div[@id='fancybox-content']//img/@src");

                if($imageQuery->length > 0){
                    foreach ($imageQuery as $key => $image){
                        $extensie = end((explode('/', $image->nodeValue)));
                        $extensie = end((explode('.', $extensie)));
                        $model = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -\/]+/","",trim($this->request->post['model']));
                        $imageName = str_replace(" ","-",trim($this->request->post['product_description']['1']['name']));
                        $imageName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+/","",$imageName);
                        $imageName .= "-".preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+/","",$model);
                        $imageName = strtolower($imageName);
                        $imageName = preg_replace("/[-]+/","-",$imageName);
                        $imageName .= '-'.rand().'.'.$extensie;
                        $imageName = 'data/'.$imageName;

                        copy($image->nodeValue, DIR_IMAGE.$imageName);
                        if($key == '0'){
                            $this->model_catalog_product->firstImage($product_id, $imageName);
                        }else{
                            $this->model_catalog_product->aditionaleImage($product_id, $imageName);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isset($this->session->data['error'])){
                        $this->session->data['error'] .= ' Produsul nu are imagini';
                    }else{
                        $this->session->data['error'] = 'Scrapper: Produsul nu are imagini.';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please help me,
Thanks

Comment: Find the index of the `?` character and use `substr()` to remove everything from that point. Someting like `$newstring = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '?'));`

Comment: my url is: example.com/upload/produse/epilatoare/SE810%20Face.jpg?maxwidth=800&maxheight=800

Comment: but I want clear url: example.com/upload/produse/epilatoare/SE810%20Face.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$yourImage = substr($yourImage, 0, strpos($yourImage','.jpg'));
```

Comment: This part `strpos( $yourImage','.jpg')` should at least be `strpos($yourImage, '.jpg')`

Comment: Thanks, but I whant, please, how modify this query for clean url: $imageQuery = $xpath->query("//div[@id='fancybox-content']//img/@src");